# C# UDP Broadcast and receive example

Tags: c#, udp

Problem:
I am trying to bind a udp socket on a specific address. I will broadcast out a message. That same socket will need to be able to receive messages.

Current code:

```
static void Main()
{
    UdpClient Configuration = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(data.IPAddress), configuration.Port));  //set up the bind to the local IP address of my choosing
    ConfigurationServer.EnableBroadcast = true;
    Configuration.Connect(new IPEndpoint(IPAddress.Parse(data.BroadcastIP), configuration.Port);
    Listen();

 }

private void Listen()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var remoteIp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, configuration.Port);
                    var data = await ConfigurationServer.ReceiveAsync();

                    // i would send based on what data i received here
                    int j = 32;
                }
            }
});
}
```

I am not receiving data on listen thread. I know that the code on the other side is functional, and sending a directed UDP message to the IP/Port combo.

Comment: This question features code that does not work as intended (ala: There is an intended feature missing). It is therefore **off-topic** for CR.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It can simply be done as

```
int PORT = 9876;
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
udpClient.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT));

var from = new IPEndPoint(0, 0);
var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        var recvBuffer = udpClient.Receive(ref from);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recvBuffer));
    }
});

var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ABCD");
udpClient.Send(data, data.Length, "255.255.255.255", PORT);

task.Wait();
```

Comment: what is 255.255.255.255 ?

Comment: @Kiquenet it's the broadcast address on a network. Messages sent to the broadcast address will be sent to all devices on a network. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address

Comment: this program exits immediately without waiting for a response

Comment: @bturner1273 It is because it is a code snippet not a complete program. If you are writing a console app, add a blocking code at the end of your *Main* function like *Console.ReadLine*

Comment: Is there a reason why you placed the `var from = new IPEndPoint(0, 0);` outside the task?

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to write a program that would send messages through a broadcast. I found an article on metanit, but it didn't really help, but the advice of that dude above helped. I want to insert my 5 cents for those who will also suddenly do this :)
That guy in the broadcast IP writes "255.255.255.255". I tried to send messages to it, but the messages did not come, but if you send them to "192.168.0.255", then these messages will reach other devices.
How to find out which IP to send packets to: in the console, write "ipconfig" and get our local IP. I have it on 192.168.0.104, so most likely the broadcast address will end with 255.
[Screenshot (ipconfig)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hh46.png)

Next, we write "arp -a" and get a list of ip addresses. Among them, we find our grid "192.168.0.104" by our local IP and look for the IP where the physical. address = "ff-ff-...".
I have 2 such IP here. Well, accordingly, I tried to send messages to both IP addresses and the IP "192.168.0.255" came up.
[Screenshot (arp -a)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLjPR.png)

By the way, going back to that top answer, the from variable will contain the local IP of the device from where the message came from. Useful for debugging.
My code example:

```
using NetworkChat.Core.Events;
using NetworkChat.Core.Models.Messages;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NetworkChat.Core.Services.Impl
{
    public class BroadcastServer : IBroadcastServer, IDisposable
    {

        private readonly string IP = "192.168.0.255";
        private readonly int Port = 8001;

        public event NewMessageHandler OnNewMessage;

        public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

        private Task ReceiveMessageTask;

        private UdpClient Client;

        public BroadcastServer()
        {
            Client = new UdpClient();
            Client.EnableBroadcast = true;
            Client.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any.Address, Port));
            ReceiveMessageTask = Task.Run(() => ReceiveMessageAsync());
        }

        public void SendMessage(Message message)
        {
            Logger.Log($"Отправка сообщения с Id {message.Id}. Отправитель: {message.SenderUserId}...");
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(message));
            Client.Send(data, data.Length, IP, Port);
            Logger.Log($"Сообщение с Id {message.Id} отправлено !");
        }

        private async Task ReceiveMessageAsync()
        {
            var from = new IPEndPoint(0, 0);
            while (true)
            {
                var result = Client.Receive(ref from);
                var message = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Message>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result));
                Logger.Log($"Получено сообщение из {from} с Id {message.Id}. Отправитель: {message.SenderUserId}");
                OnNewMessage.Invoke(message);
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            ReceiveMessageTask.Dispose();
            Client.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```