# C# local network discovery of own agents

Tags: c#, sockets, p2p, software-distribution, fileserver

I have this piece of software, let's call it an agent, deployed on every machine in a local network. Every once in a while, it needs to pull an update from the server.
That means, each machine in that network connects to my server and downloads the new version which is a few MB.

What i want to achieve:
Once the first machine pulls the update from the server, the other machines should get the update from the one(s) that already got it, in a peer network.

The ideas i have so far:

1. Use a shared folder in the network, first machine that gets the
   update places it into that shared folder. Every machine checks the
   shared folder first before going to my server. This works, but i get
   problems if sharing is not enabled in windows, firewalls, access
   rights, etc.
2. Each agent opens a socket available to the internal network (probably open a tcp socket on 127.0.0.1 on a random port that all
   the agents know about). Before pulling the update, broadcast to the
   network that you request an update, and if nobody replies that they
   have the update, proceed to the server. Else, get the update from
   the agent who replied, since they probably already got the update
   from the server or from some other agents. The problems i have here
   is that i don't really know how to proceed with the network
   discovery, nor the performance impact this could have.
3. Build a local server app, publish it on some node of the internal network (one of the computers) that all the other agents connect to
   for updates. This local server gets the update only the first time,
   and it "caches" it, giving it to any agent requesting it. This is my
   least favorite option, since it implies a local server. If that one
   fails, no other node can get updates. Of course, i can implement
   fallback mechanism to go to the real server, but still. And also,
   every agent will need to know exactly who the "master" is, and that
   would be even harder to manage.

If you guys have any better ideas, or any guides to lead me to, would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you

- either have to maintain a list of the computers that already have the update and pick one randomly to acquire the update,
- or have a broadcast query that all computer with the update respond and pick one.

I would go with the broadcast in the spirit of peer-to-peer.

Comment: I favour this the best, but, do you happen to have some learning material about this? As far as i know, the broadcast address is the network address with the last bytes filled with ones (typically if the network address is 192.168.0.0, the broadcast would be 192.168.0.255, taking the mask is 255.255.255.0). But how do i know to listen? Will it work if every agent just listens to localhost on a random port, let's say 8384?

Comment: Please refer to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616911/c-sharp-udp-broadcast-and-receive-example