# udpclient receives broadcast only locally (c#, Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, udpclient, receiver

I want to receive a UDP message which was broadcasted to 255.255.255.255 with a `UdpClient` within Unity.
But whatever combination of settings I try, it only receives a message, if it was sent from localhost.
I have tried fitted example code from these resources, non worked:

- https://gist.github.com/michaelosthege/857acac92b8ee689a6bb30d5bf23d9f6
- [C# UDP Broadcast and receive example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616911/c-sharp-udp-broadcast-and-receive-example)
- [UdpClient receive on broadcast address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746519/udpclient-receive-on-broadcast-address)
- [How to do Network discovery using UDP broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852781/how-to-do-network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast)

I'm running the Code below a task.

```
private void Listen()
{
    udpClient = new UdpClient(9000);
    //udpClient.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9000));
    //udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
    //udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    //udpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
    //broadcastAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9000);
    //udpClient.Client.Bind(broadcastAddress);
    //udpClient.Connect(broadcastAddress);
    //var from = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9000);
    var from = new IPEndPoint(0, 0);

    while (true)
    {
        var receive = udpClient.Receive(ref from);
        var msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receive);
        Debug.Log($"Received message \"{msg}\"");
        Debug.Log($"from {from}  ({from.Address})");
    }
}
```

I have used several of the commented lines in combination.

- When I send something from within the same Application to 255.255.255.255 with another `UdpClient` on port 9000, it works as expected.
- When I send something from any other machine on the network to 255.255.255.255

  - any machine in the network receives it (checking with PacketSender on osx devices)
  - On the windows machine I'm developing this application on, the message is received by UdpSenderReceiver
  - But the udpClient from within Unity does not receive anything - and the Firewall does not ask or tell me anything.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: I'm onto something: it appears to be some Firewall Problem, because it seems to work, when i turn the windows firewall off.
I'm just puzzled that it works without a problem with the UdpSenderReceiver tool ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Windows Defender by default blocks the Unity Editor (but not *UdpSenderReceiver*).

I had to resolve it by Admitting the Unity Editor on the public domain

[image]

The Rules for

- Unity 2019.3.3f1 Editor
- Unity 2019.3.4f1 Editor

had been present and were not modified.
I modified the Rule for Unity 2019.2.4f1 Editor in order to allow access from the public domain (I simply allowed all domains).